# Remove null variable name and value both while echoing in a single string

Tags: shell, programming

i have the below condition where values are as below.

```
emp_name="Sid"
emp_id=1234
emp_hobby=""
emp_likes="swimming"
emp_dislikes=""

emp_summary="emp_name:$emp_name,emp_id:$emp_id,emp_hobby:$emp_hobby,emp_likes:$emp_likes,emp_dislikes:$emp_dislikes"
```

if I echo above with the values that are provided as an example it will give result as

`"emp_name:"Sid",emp_id:1234,emp_hobby:,empf_likes:"swimming",emp_dislikes:"`

I need help with a dynamic code where if any of the value is null that complete variable is removed from the echo as below

`"emp_name:"Sid",emp_id:1234,emp_likes:"swimming"`

i tried {parameter:+word} returns the values but not sure how to deal with the variable name itself.

Comment: Are you creating JSON?

Comment: If you're creating a JSON object, it would be better to keep the null values in there, but as `null`.  It's easiest to do this using `jo`: `jo emp_name="$emp_name" emp_id="$emp_id" emp_hobby="$emp_hobby" emp_likes="$emp_likes" emp_dislikes="$emp_dislikes"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `${parameter:+word}` expansion, you just need to put the static part, the variable name, in the right-hand side too:

```
$ emp_name=""; echo "-${emp_name:+emp_name:$emp_name}-"
--
$ emp_name="foo bar"; echo "-${emp_name:+emp_name:$emp_name}-"
-emp_name:foo bar-
```

Note that the way you showed that in the question, you have an additional problem: the commas. You could use `"${emp_name:+emp_name:$emp_name}"`, but if you do that to all the variables, you'll have a trailing comma at the end of the line. You could remove that with `${str%,}` if you store the string in the variable `str` first.

Doing that for all the variables is a bit repetitive, though. If you're using Bash, you could use namerefs to point to the variables, and collect the text to a string variable:

```
str=()
for varname in emp_name emp_id emp_hobby emp_likes emp_dislikes; do
    declare -n var=$varname
    if [[ -n "$var" ]]; then
        str+="$varname:$var,"
    fi
done
str=${str%,}
printf "%s\n" "$str"
```

With your values, that prints `emp_name:Sid,emp_id:1234,emp_likes:swimming`.
There's usually no difference between string variables and numeric variables in the shell, and if you want quotes or such around the values, you'll have to do something else. In Bash, you could use `printf %q`, or `${var@Q}` to get the value in a format that's suitable for shell input, i.e. with all embedded quotes properly escaped, too.

You could also use an associative array there instead of the pile of independent variables.

(Bash has `declare -i` to make a variable into an integer, but it still prints the same as a string, and I don't think there's an easy way to determine if the variable is a string or an integer.)

Comment: Thanks , this is right and it worked.